# Delete/replace img tags in post content for auto published posts

Tags: wpdb, regex

In my blog I have set up auto-publish for posts and I get 5 thousands new posts every day, in this moment I have more than 150 thousand posts.

I need a script, or a plugin, or a function to connect to my database and strip out all `img` tags from post content.

I know the regular expression to match the img tags, but I can't find a script for using this regular expression

```
<img[^>]+\>
```

to replace imgs in already published posts and to prevent new posts to contain image tags.

I found [this class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) and I think that it will achieve my goal but I am not sure how to edit this

```
$wpdb->query(
  "UPDATE $wpdb->posts SET post_parent = 7
  WHERE ID = 15
  AND post_status = 'static'"
);
```

to fit my needs.

**please note:** my site is using some auto publish posts feature
Any ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) to get all your post, and then use a foreach cycle to replace the img tags using the regex you posted and then use [`wp_update_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post) to change post content:

```
function remove_images_form_past_posts() {    
  if ( get_transient('images_removed_from_past') ) return;
  $posts = get_posts('nopaging=1');    
  if ( $posts ) {
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
      $newcontent = preg_replace('/<img[^>]+\>/i', '', $post->post_content);
      $newpost = array( 'ID' => $post->ID, 'post_content' => $newcontent);
      wp_update_post($newpost);
    }
    set_transient('images_removed_from_past', 1);
  }
}

add_action('admin_init','remove_images_form_past_posts');
```

This code should be used only once, to change the past posts content. To ensure it runs only once I've used a transient. See Codex for [Transient API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API).

Now you have to add a function that hook into `'wp_insert_post_data'` filter hook and prevent new posts are added with images:

```
function remove_images_before_publish( $data, $postarr ) {
  if ( ! empty($data['post_content']) )
    $data['post_content'] = preg_replace('/<img[^>]+\>/i', '', $data['post_content']);
  return $data;
}
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data','remove_images_before_publish', 20, 2);
```

Comment: fine, but how to implement this with $wpdb . or you mean that i don't need $wpdb at all?

Comment: using this once! but i need to using this every day because i  have 5 thousands new post every day. can i add to your code where expression to put post_date?

Comment: i will do, but it is true i need to update my past & future posts @G. M.

Comment: iam already updated it, thank you very very much for your help, iam really appreciate your help. iam sorry for this stupid question where i can put this code. or how to make this a plugin?

Comment: iam already voted & accepted your answer, does this 2 functions will use alot of memory or slow down the site load speed

Comment: could you please edit the second function, to let the posts as it for some hours lets say 10 hours & after 10 hours clean the post or any some thing like this?

Comment: this is new question , i will waiting for your answers
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/116376/delete-replace-img-tags-in-post-content-for-auto-published-posts-after-10-hours